# Android Service PendingIntent no callback from Service in the Activity (Fragment)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, service, android-pendingintent

I am trying to trigger the `onActivityResult` method from a `Service` using `PendingIntent`.
Everything goes fine: background thread works perfectly, `PendingIntent` sends an `Intent` object to a `Fragment`, but it does not run the `onActivityResult` method.

Here is my code for `Service` creation:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), UpdaterService.class);
Intent ei = new Intent();
PendingIntent pi = getActivity().createPendingResult(TASK_CODE_UPDATE, ei, 0);
```

onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "Result get");
    if(resultCode == RESULT_START){
        switch(requestCode){
        case TASK_CODE_UPDATE:
            lessonTextView.setText(data.getStringExtra(UpdaterService.EXTRA_LESSON_VIEW_TEXT));
            futureTextView.setText(data.getStringExtra(UpdaterService.EXTRA_FUTURE_VIEW_TEXT));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Service sending code:

```
Intent i = new Intent()
    .putExtra(EXTRA_LESSON_VIEW_TEXT, lessonViewText)
    .putExtra(EXTRA_FUTURE_VIEW_TEXT, futureViewText);
try {
    pi.send(UpdaterService.this, HelperFragment.RESULT_START, i);
    Log.d(TAG, "Sending intent");
} catch (CanceledException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e(TAG, "Error sending intent");
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `createPendingResult()` method, so I can't comment on why it's not working, but you should probably use [binding](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) instead.

Comment: To send information from your `Service` back to your `Activity`, you can either use a bound service with callback interface, or you could send the results as a broadcast `Intent` (with `sendBroadcast()`) and have your `Activity` register a `BroadcastReceiver` to get the results.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct use of the `Intent` for result.  That is only used when calling `startActivityForResult()` from one `Activity` to another.  From your `Service` when you call `pi.send()` you are effectively doing a `startActivity()` with the contents of the `PendingIntent`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `PendingIntent` from `createPendingResult()` to pass information from a service to an activity works — when the service calls `pendingIntent.send()`,  the `onActivityResult()` method of the activity is invoked. However, there are some caveats:

1. There is no way to get the `onActivityResult()` callback in a fragment — receiving the result must be handled directly in the activity.
2. When the activity receiving the result is not running (e.g., the user switched to another app while the background operation was in progress), the `onActivityResult()` method will not be called immediately — instead, the data from all `pendingIntent.send()` calls will be queued, and when the activity is started again, it will receive all those queued `onActivityResult()` calls at once.